# How to stop a navigation from being fixed at certain point?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a fixed navigation with an extra class called "fixed",
which activates when you scroll down.

CSS:

```
.fixed {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $(".mod_customnav").addClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

I want it to stop being fixed at a certain point, so that you can scroll further down without the navigation-menu but it should also stay in place (the place where it stopped).

I tried to implement that like this:

CSS:

```
.unfixed {
  position:relative;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 50) {
        $(".mod_customnav").removeClass('fixed');
        $(".mod_customnav").addClass('unfixed');
    }
});
```

When I do that it

1. Doesn't stay in place
2. Blocks you from scrolling down further

Any help or suggestion is appreciated!

**JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/a0mf68ho/1/**

Comment: `a sticky navigation` ... no ... you have a fixed navigation ... `position: sticky` is something else altogether

Comment: I cant use position:sticky because nothing happens then. Also that wouldn't solve my problem even if it was position: sticky.

Comment: yes - exactly - so that's what I was pointing out, there's nothing "sticky" about it ... `I cant use position:sticky` you can, you just don't understand how

Comment: Even with position:sticky it won't work so I dont know how this is related to anything, but for you I changed the topic name :). Still got the same problem.

Comment: I understand you have a problem, just saying that using the phrase "sticky" means something else

Comment: "*so that you can scroll further down without the navigation-menu but it should also stay in place*" - little unclear this - so it's "fixed" to the top as you scroll down, then when you get to p2 it stops being "fixed" to the top, but then "stays in place" - but if it's scroll off the top then it doesn't matter?   Other than this part, position:sticky seems to be what you're looking for (despite comments to the contrary)  https://jsfiddle.net/rh9ned2p/

Comment: When you scroll down it should always be on top. When you get to p2 it should stop being "fixed" and then stay above p2. you kinda get what i mean? its really hard to explain for me at least (english's not my first language obviously). when you scroll up from p2 the nav should be fixed again.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute instead of relative(placing the div relative to its parent element)

```
.unfixed {
  position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: does not really work sadly :(